# Store OwnableState in a node which is not the owner?

Tags: corda

According to [this](https://docs.corda.net/api-states.html?highlight=relevant#the-vault) only owner stores the OwnableState in it's vault. 
Is there a way for the a node which is not the owner to store the state?

In my scenario, the transfer happens from A -> B and A needs to know the B's balance at all times.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

The owner node can call [SendTransactionFlow](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.flows/-send-transaction-flow/index.html) after calling FinalityFlow and send the transaction to the other party.

Whereas the other party will then need to call [ReceiveTransactionFlow](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.flows/-receive-transaction-flow/index.html) with the parameter StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE

This is also possible via the Two-sided FinalityFlow in [Corda 4](https://docs.corda.net/head/release-notes.html#security-upgrades)

**Option 2:**

We can ditch OwnableState altogether and make the state implement just the ContractState class. This way all the participants and not just the owner will store the state in their vault.